# Unable to retrieve access_token with iron-ajax response handler in Polymer

Tags: json, ajax, polymer, token, polymer-1.0

I am using iron-ajax in my Polymer project to login a user. After sending the user details to the database I need to return a token if the login succeeds. However, I am having trouble with the response. It would be great If someone could look over my code and tell me what I am missing.
Currently the console returns me undefined when I output the repos property. Below is the code of my iron-ajax my properties and the function that gets called when a user sends the details.
In addition I added what I am trying to return.

```
<dom-module id="login-form">
  <template>    
    <iron-ajax
      id="requestUser"
      url="http://api.dev/oauth/token"
      handle-as="json"
      method="POST"
      content-type="application/json"
      body='{
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": 2,
        "client_secret": "KyHacYa2Q7DCTVLaDe1RSnvTlTI20CrmYb7FXujb",
        "username": "user1@test.com",
        "password": "1111",
        "scope": "*"}'
      last-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>

    </template>
    <script>

    Polymer({
      is: 'login-form',
      properties: {
        repos: {
          type: Array
        },
      },

      //On-tap loginTheUser runs
      loginTheUser: function() {
        this.$.requestUser.generateRequest();
      },
      handleResponse: function (data) {
        this.repos = data.details.response;
        console.log(this.repos);
      },

   </script>
</dom-module>
```

The following is the token i try to get returned:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3155673599,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1...",
  "refresh_token": "271VWcUXisybg="
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<iron-ajax>.lastResponse`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-lastResponse) is actually an `Object` that represents the last received response from the AJAX request. You could [bind](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#property-binding) that to a property in your markup (it seems `repos` is the target):

```
<iron-ajax last-response="{{repos}}">
```

You were passing a method name, which implies you're actually trying to set a handler for the [`<iron-ajax>.response`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#event-response) event. To do that, you could create an [annotated event listener](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners) with:

```
<iron-ajax on-response="handleResponse">
```

Note that your response handler is incorrectly trying to read `data.details` when it should be `data.detail` (where `data` is a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)).